# Bison print character which caused an error

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm developing a simple compiler with Bison and Flex. My grammar only accepts strings `[a-z]+`. If the input is `a0` I would like to display an error message, something along the lines of 'unrecognized character 0'. For now, every non-grammar things are intercepted by `.` in the end. So string `a0` is causing syntax error. I did set Bison `parse.error` to verbose but it gives me tokens that are useless for the user. Is there a way that I could display what I want, i.e. show the user what exactly is wrong with the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easiest to do in the lexer rather than the parser.  If your lexer (.l file) ends with a rule like:

```
.    { yyerror("ignoring unrecognized character '%c' in input", *yytext); }
```

then the bogus characters will simply be skipped (and the message printed).  Alternately, you can return them as (single) tokens to the parser

```
.    { return *yytext; }
```

and then if you set `%define parser.error verbose` in your bison code you'll get syntax errors that display the unexpected token and which token(s) were expected.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong - I have `yyerror` defined in my .y file so I added `extern yyerror` in .l file and the first option you mentioned. Still I'm only getting the syntax error message.

Comment: a "syntax error" message from the parser means your lexer is returning some token that is not valid in the current context, and you don't have `parse.error verbose` set.  Adding that will extend the syntax error to include the tokens returned and expected.